# Identify records within set time window and set radius

Tags: r, distance

Sample data are here

```
dat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 
18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 
18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18322, 
18322, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18353, 
18353, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18383, 
18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 
18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 
18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 
18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 
18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 
18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 
18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18414, 
18414), class = "Date"), Latitude = c(-38.27979018, -38.28800834, 
-38.28789426, -38.28784711, -38.28811226, -38.24901162, -38.24883835, 
-38.24813538, -38.22090536, -38.21794456, -33.65843804, -33.65186087, 
-33.65167827, -28.20582, -28.113105, -28.165569, -27.774506, 
-38.00005322, -37.99989388, -38.00010574, -38.00000075, -38.07617281, 
-38.07609913, -34.65315707, -35.26145798, -35.26116437, -35.19897279, 
-35.21582798, -35.21423268, -35.21719149, -35.2170287, -35.21398904, 
-35.21903629, -35.23535402, -35.34670565, -34.33938683, -34.33912228, 
-34.52404584, -34.52444265, -34.52704253, -34.52745493, -34.5247304, 
-34.52417366, -34.52293983, -34.52295027, -34.52259672, -34.5222423, 
-24.65406727, -34.54034238, -34.53884619, -34.53872005, -34.50131898, 
-34.53874632, -34.53877457, -34.53870469, -34.54425339, -34.54243065, 
-34.54538206, -34.54556464, -34.53927106, -34.54548039, -34.53805039, 
-34.59546385, -34.53951217, -34.53972007, -34.53968709, -34.54129251, 
-34.54157801, -34.52108506, -34.51357922, -34.50956363, -34.50407227, 
-34.50181401, -34.50179899, -34.57352559, -34.57352559, -34.57352559, 
-34.57352559, -34.50177717, -34.50197525, -34.29277759, -34.53272862, 
-34.53471251, -34.53710379, -34.53790585, -34.51302587, -34.51432598, 
-34.44278577, -34.44455991, -34.44654596, -34.49461172, -34.45127815, 
-34.45252009, -34.4554307, -34.48326704, -34.48215664, -34.46379689, 
-34.46799855, -34.46869444, -34.4706235, -38.09604587, -38.09607506, 
-38.09607778, -34.94664925, -34.94802351, -34.95624831, -34.88059837, 
-34.87884777, -34.87814746, -34.91532504, -34.78718988, -34.78722401, 
-34.78719558, -34.78719558, -34.8375538, -34.78755033, -34.78735561, 
-34.79254583, -34.86922824, -34.79243903, -38.09620777, -38.09622748, 
-38.09615627, -34.86885017, -38.09648193, -38.09651753, -38.0965639, 
-38.09653311, -34.85810442, -34.85744037, -34.63433391, -34.85605209, 
-34.80740041, -34.6351988, -38.09776547, -38.09774539, -34.64151502, 
-34.64114571, -34.80232941, -38.09735647, -34.64055764, -34.64011977, 
-38.09734867, -34.64764014, -34.64695161, -34.64615269, -34.64625285, 
-34.64575052, -38.09743711, -38.09875514, -34.79839001, -34.79569787, 
-34.79715369, -38.09904487, -38.09890566, -38.09893513, -34.79915008, 
-38.09897196, -34.80206308, -38.09864916, -34.80231237, -38.0984301, 
-38.09840958, -38.09836382, -34.80273659, -34.8026447, -38.09918422, 
-34.55181621, -38.09911821, -34.55183117, -38.09906339, -34.55201423, 
-34.55096746, -34.55098716, -38.09741839, -38.09742922, -38.09738947, 
-38.09736362, -34.80011318, -35.28813132, -34.79995225, -35.2878537, 
-34.79717391, -38.09738274, -38.097137, -34.79645161, -38.09725434, 
-38.09725139, -35.29857362, -35.30041032, -35.25804353, -35.26385998, 
-35.32227471, -35.25578323, -35.32234395, -35.25095031, -35.25107114, 
-35.37568854, -35.38482157, -35.38449521, -35.37903454, -35.37792207, 
-35.37290121, -35.37045732, -35.36843869, -35.36092285, -35.33364693, 
-35.29924817, -35.29408346, -35.29112726, -35.29776277, -35.31030859, 
-35.27154045, -35.27161924, -35.27382061, -35.26652115, -35.26826836, 
-35.26826237, -35.26514812, -38.09725723, -34.99652033, -38.09684417, 
-38.09679523, -38.09670169, -34.97171924, -34.97151715, -38.09675547, 
-38.09676363, -34.96630909, -38.09669293, -38.09652381, -38.09651091, 
-35.30703615, -38.09659594, -38.09651892, -38.09656563, -38.09656751, 
-38.09654629, -38.09657122, -38.0966747, -38.09662602, -38.09666504, 
-38.09665758, -38.09663016, -38.09666452, -38.09671974, -38.0973105, 
-34.95977022, -34.96555913, -38.09874384, -34.98105042, -34.99314576, 
-34.9935624, -34.99672559, -38.05654208, -38.05586677, -38.05482561, 
-38.05418861, -35.01285627, -35.01316422, -35.02903966, -35.01750178, 
-35.01632765, -35.36783768, -35.38074309, -35.38476152, -35.39223747, 
-35.39224297, -35.39577956, -35.38997825, -35.39005442, -35.4116153, 
-35.41161735, -35.39916579, -35.40087905, -34.55206951, -34.55184198, 
-34.55178788, -34.55100656, -34.55106716, -35.38023662, -34.64113457, 
-34.6405874, -34.6401849, -34.64576381, -34.64612054, -34.6470804, 
-35.06148071, -35.06153806, -38.05725923, -38.05720772, -38.05305395, 
-38.05314006, -38.05235234, -38.05259125, -38.05309487, -34.64631094, 
-34.64627607, -38.02699494, -34.64567278, -38.02704924, -34.6471697, 
-34.64765011, -34.64938609, -38.02686297, -38.02669005, -34.655151, 
-38.02666041, -34.63444585, -38.02795399, -38.02740171, -34.63516699, 
-34.64145182, -34.64011273, -38.02668967, -38.0266911, -34.64153916, 
-34.64112254, -34.64058044, -38.0263438, -34.6397425, -34.63964791, 
-34.55249808, -34.55180808, -34.55186286, -34.55209835, -34.55209835, 
-34.55219411, -34.55096867, -34.5509056, -34.539523, -34.54681179, 
-38.02318169, -38.02304489, -38.0242108, -38.02490784, -38.02489315, 
-38.02496554, -38.02525737, -34.5518134, -38.02542613, -38.02536861, 
-34.55188268, -38.02565251, -38.02552369, -38.02549775, -38.0255219, 
-38.02554113, -38.02551175, -38.02554436, -38.02551253, -38.02565542, 
-38.02566181, -38.025693, -38.02588032, -38.02617132, -34.63449639, 
-38.02567543, -34.63507684, -34.64118268, -34.64153007, -34.64153007, 
-34.64058819, -34.65110136, -34.647609, -23.40569506, -34.55212634, 
-34.54674541, -34.53958157, -34.63436509, -34.63529938, -34.63957729, 
-34.64949635, -34.6456841, -34.6469685, -33.711065, -33.553032, 
-33.554087, -33.558334, -33.660084, -33.664013, -33.408499, -33.403215, 
-33.362946, -33.300805, -33.272926, -33.451745, -33.464974, -33.602226, 
-33.603861, -38.32518413, -33.921939, -38.32521227, -33.922549, 
-33.92388, -33.92481, -33.926194, -33.927017, -33.926407, -33.923803, 
-33.923647, -33.924435, -33.925445, -33.926598, -33.924294, -33.925358, 
-33.92579, -33.926159, -33.927134, -33.926667, -33.926992, -33.926943, 
-38.32531961, -33.924815, -33.923796, -33.922029, -33.92113, 
-33.921526, -33.923311, -33.923823, -33.924938, -33.926371, -33.920856, 
-33.920852, -33.921862, -33.922921, -33.924185, -33.926313, -33.928174, 
-33.928646, -33.929385, -33.927507, -33.928486, -33.930213, -33.929839, 
-33.92943, -33.928878, -33.929109, -38.32553341, -33.930088, 
-33.949109, -33.949314, -33.948789, -33.948139, -33.947912, -38.32549008, 
-33.47059, -33.470293, -33.47032, -33.469674, -33.470021, -33.470417, 
-33.469935, -33.470189, -33.470189, -33.469592, -33.469304, -33.469304, 
-33.470298, -33.469875, -33.469419, -33.46882, -33.469776, -33.466557, 
-33.466557, -33.466709, -33.467532, -33.46755, -33.468011, -33.468231, 
-33.468523, -33.468055, -33.468467, -33.467993, -33.81440345, 
-33.814461, -38.27012579, -38.26996867, -38.26910495, -38.26899143, 
-38.26850853, -38.2685746, -38.26865359, -38.26858669, -38.26857552, 
-38.2778032, -38.27920573, -38.27936727, -38.27865625, -38.278612, 
-38.27796336, -38.27810932, -38.06795493, -38.0679971, -38.0675927, 
-38.06524019, -38.06301333, -38.18621, -35.54827882, -35.5479794, 
-38.06528803, -38.0653496, -34.51407887, -34.51194309, -38.06361907, 
-38.0635856, -38.06353191, -38.06342864, -38.06328669, -38.0630865, 
-38.06305254, -34.37529291, -34.37410315, -34.3741794, -34.38651516, 
-34.38641885, -34.3776708, -34.38668333, -34.38797361, -38.0681196, 
-38.06802474, -34.40466492, -38.06765977, -38.06760334, -34.37165722, 
-38.0677717, -38.06789243, -38.06798642, -34.30642052, -34.30462157, 
-34.30427723, -34.47067488, -34.33917109, -34.33927172, -34.33936166, 
-34.51299971, -34.51299686, -34.33933454, -34.53705829, -34.36446148, 
-38.27448383, -38.2736734, -38.27367845, -38.27356423, -38.27882936, 
-38.27858959, -38.27845253, -38.27845239, -38.27843063, -38.27808271, 
-38.27813859, -38.27813451, -34.12362585, -34.50179681, -34.50178986, 
-34.50185283, -34.50192137, -34.5019594, -34.5018563, -34.49929032, 
-34.50370136, -34.49975881, -34.51185799, -34.51408176, -34.49941168, 
-34.50037365, -34.50105394, -34.50141794, -34.50130694, -34.59693868, 
-34.50094236, -34.50080947, -34.50059569, -34.50051833, -34.50026275, 
-34.50010389, -34.59379705, -34.49979308, -34.499472, -34.59390756, 
-34.59394592, -34.59456134, -34.59487213, -34.59519469, -34.59628342, 
-34.59185228, -34.59205812, -34.59234665, -34.59225496, -34.59236109, 
-34.50195758, -34.50203017, -34.50194691, -34.59300472, -34.5018621, 
-34.59315367, -34.50175377, -34.59341597, -34.50169415, -34.50157458, 
-34.59413221, -34.50154772, -34.59342806, -34.50142738, -34.5933983, 
-34.5014218, -34.59305661, -36.400569, -33.96224917, -38.20209412, 
-33.93425742, -33.96649738, -38.02382469, -38.02383288, -38.02422812, 
-33.95998864, -33.8323927, -33.83994383, -33.93290233, -33.46710427, 
-33.4548374, -33.45645268, -33.4551047, -33.45444663, -33.45820324, 
-33.4634822, -33.46389199, -33.46828956, -33.83240374, -38.31090474, 
-38.31053772, -38.31138173, -38.3117633, -38.31231974, -38.31216289, 
-38.31206222, -38.3118364, -38.31219572, -38.31244691, -33.95140413, 
-33.45319635, -33.45255584, -33.44505559, -33.4441068, -33.44431463, 
-33.44279981, -33.4429926, -33.44217896, -33.44103282, -33.44067404, 
-33.43954692, -33.44009648, -33.44153184, -33.44154982, -35.38899846, 
-35.3936663, -35.44757065, -33.88396817, -33.88141385, -33.92854669, 
-33.944987, -33.77705719, -33.46392921, -33.45851778, -33.45459253, 
-33.45521062, -33.45526948, -33.45593001, -33.45865301, -33.46352635, 
-33.46562333), Longitude = c(144.2602623, 144.2650222, 144.2642341, 
144.2642518, 144.2683644, 144.2128636, 144.2117641, 144.2050393, 
144.1925314, 144.1925662, 151.1362792, 151.1412145, 151.139815, 
114.881665, 114.975678, 114.951207, 115.106505, 145.128549, 145.1292347, 
145.1289365, 145.1289006, 144.4610305, 144.4610269, 150.4906709, 
141.6046361, 141.6014747, 141.6762058, 141.5773895, 141.5069921, 
141.5922895, 141.5940582, 141.596138, 141.5947167, 141.5901569, 
141.0692235, 141.1180323, 141.1048137, 141.4271159, 141.4272181, 
141.4271038, 141.426893, 141.4269487, 141.4267584, 141.4269025, 
141.42691, 141.4267534, 141.4269364, 113.7035079, 142.2188841, 
142.2471798, 142.2477034, 142.3330793, 142.2490804, 142.2495225, 
142.2492486, 142.313168, 142.2726975, 142.3185027, 142.3187974, 
142.2426488, 142.3189334, 142.2361602, 142.1195537, 142.2216135, 
142.2209567, 142.2203954, 142.2160015, 142.2148488, 142.1240568, 
142.1330192, 142.1377101, 142.1441212, 142.2320071, 142.2309509, 
150.5228685, 150.5228685, 150.5228685, 150.5228685, 142.2231243, 
142.1984475, 142.0579531, 141.4967186, 141.4966764, 141.4968306, 
141.4967476, 141.4268839, 141.4268163, 141.427063, 141.4271249, 
141.4270479, 141.4268962, 141.4270234, 141.427129, 141.4269958, 
141.4269073, 141.426804, 141.4270817, 141.4271538, 141.4270799, 
141.4268725, 144.0453592, 144.0451694, 144.0447606, 142.3791656, 
142.3791608, 142.3791475, 142.3421226, 142.3421329, 142.3421454, 
142.3435419, 142.3654575, 142.3643338, 142.360928, 142.360928, 
142.3566555, 142.3642432, 142.3641826, 142.3702007, 142.3072166, 
142.3701519, 144.0468037, 144.046814, 144.0468777, 142.3082583, 
144.0472175, 144.047129, 144.0471155, 144.0471954, 142.3122493, 
142.3135573, 150.4863096, 142.3201616, 142.4202412, 150.4833592, 
144.04823, 144.048372, 150.4854611, 150.4852705, 142.4494608, 
144.0485605, 150.4850197, 150.4851976, 144.049015, 150.4877273, 
150.487568, 150.4871309, 150.4872959, 150.4870301, 144.0490557, 
144.050841, 142.4613191, 142.4622482, 142.4616165, 144.0512869, 
144.051347, 144.0513219, 142.4610072, 144.0516914, 142.457931, 
144.0522037, 142.4598972, 144.0519231, 144.0517758, 144.0517074, 
142.4688054, 142.4692053, 144.0523228, 150.4804385, 144.052374, 
150.4813113, 144.0524018, 150.4815011, 150.4787111, 150.4788725, 
144.0545307, 144.0544734, 144.0543674, 144.0537182, 142.4864625, 
142.1878288, 142.4865242, 142.1733784, 142.487577, 144.0538272, 
144.0542104, 142.4878649, 144.0543045, 144.0542978, 142.2009586, 
142.2011857, 142.1935556, 142.2077734, 142.1866757, 142.1928294, 
142.1843998, 142.1877663, 142.1865989, 142.1026735, 142.0749383, 
142.0747303, 142.067896, 142.0657974, 142.0583195, 142.0575489, 
142.0554327, 142.0479054, 142.0341827, 142.0583558, 142.0590826, 
142.0568725, 142.0581648, 142.1956365, 142.2012105, 142.2010387, 
142.2019807, 142.2118941, 142.2105677, 142.2105757, 142.2148197, 
144.0549173, 142.6617428, 144.0566673, 144.0565859, 144.056624, 
142.6597051, 142.6597382, 144.0566897, 144.0566599, 142.6595455, 
144.0565998, 144.0565587, 144.0566254, 142.2654209, 144.0566529, 
144.0567251, 144.057067, 144.0570354, 144.0571841, 144.0571564, 
144.0571907, 144.0572924, 144.0572819, 144.0573491, 144.0573863, 
144.0575457, 144.0580825, 144.0597325, 142.6594351, 142.659427, 
144.0610594, 142.6597196, 142.6603163, 142.6607313, 142.6615727, 
144.1625813, 144.1630648, 144.1623874, 144.1623875, 142.6974037, 
142.6973811, 142.6633424, 142.6979845, 142.6979954, 142.0540012, 
142.0695246, 142.074471, 142.0744589, 142.0738231, 142.0116265, 
142.0367169, 142.0357093, 142.0653119, 142.0652154, 142.0074609, 
142.0042888, 150.4814855, 150.4814124, 150.4804031, 150.4789532, 
150.4787758, 142.0973395, 150.4852898, 150.4850514, 150.4848594, 
150.4868506, 150.487141, 150.4875173, 138.6508021, 138.6508323, 
144.1613789, 144.1613164, 144.1636444, 144.1633689, 144.1638399, 
144.1641021, 144.1647283, 150.4872073, 150.4871017, 144.05103, 
150.4869309, 144.051212, 150.4872269, 150.4877971, 150.4885517, 
144.0505588, 144.0504153, 150.491569, 144.0501795, 150.486231, 
144.0490946, 144.0493186, 150.4833086, 150.4854427, 150.4849562, 
144.0496126, 144.049575, 150.4854554, 150.4852967, 150.485169, 
144.0484155, 150.4850161, 150.4849702, 150.4816312, 150.4813822, 
150.4803151, 150.4809236, 150.4809236, 150.48019, 150.4787507, 
150.4790367, 150.483022, 150.4778087, 144.0547136, 144.0551254, 
144.0514715, 144.0512551, 144.0512413, 144.0512312, 144.0513592, 
150.4814239, 144.0512622, 144.051282, 150.481142, 144.050542, 
144.0508365, 144.0511728, 144.0511487, 144.0511857, 144.0511078, 
144.0510512, 144.0510574, 144.0509362, 144.0508881, 144.0507839, 
144.0504305, 144.0497043, 150.4862482, 144.0488682, 150.4834525, 
150.48524, 150.4854741, 150.4854741, 150.485037, 150.4892594, 
150.487751, 145.2492723, 150.4813, 150.4778064, 150.4830569, 
150.4862533, 150.4832882, 150.485002, 150.4885451, 150.4870724, 
150.4874888, 119.541365, 119.676327, 119.677197, 119.67453, 119.777374, 
119.784603, 119.521579, 119.50289, 119.804846, 119.671719, 119.712121, 
120.139529, 120.149206, 120.236686, 120.236729, 144.2623103, 
120.132219, 144.2625977, 120.130352, 120.130642, 120.132647, 
120.130625, 120.129708, 120.128884, 120.12927, 120.127875, 120.127778, 
120.127746, 120.127684, 120.124608, 120.125021, 120.124501, 120.123385, 
120.124093, 120.122022, 120.119737, 120.117375, 144.2627286, 
120.119192, 120.120635, 120.11968, 120.121826, 120.118758, 120.118436, 
120.115636, 120.115336, 120.116098, 120.116962, 120.115573, 120.114094, 
120.113794, 120.113451, 120.114073, 120.115618, 120.116916, 120.118643, 
120.120285, 120.121294, 120.12065, 120.122238, 120.124491, 120.126143, 
120.128718, 144.2644381, 120.126358, 120.12481, 120.123716, 120.123673, 
120.123673, 120.124703, 144.2643392, 143.333649, 143.333226, 
143.332932, 143.332747, 143.332397, 143.331901, 143.331889, 143.331175, 
143.331175, 143.331174, 143.331224, 143.331224, 143.330311, 143.327232, 
143.325434, 143.325223, 143.324617, 143.325335, 143.325335, 143.324463, 
143.323408, 143.322775, 143.322697, 143.322415, 143.322123, 143.32204, 
143.321863, 143.321726, 151.0395066, 151.040085, 144.4473823, 
144.4470197, 144.4472375, 144.4472647, 144.4473514, 144.4472558, 
144.4473179, 144.4472879, 144.4472514, 144.4643034, 144.4708655, 
144.4724737, 144.4737736, 144.4750037, 144.4749125, 144.4623651, 
144.5135347, 144.5135156, 144.5140278, 144.5129077, 144.5121757, 
145.344926, 143.8132222, 143.8135158, 144.5129449, 144.5128911, 
142.1320618, 142.134758, 144.5138541, 144.5138644, 144.5139933, 
144.5134095, 144.5133682, 144.512612, 144.5121981, 141.2394892, 
141.2104093, 141.2095446, 141.3146106, 141.3177617, 141.1971203, 
141.3178289, 141.3226534, 144.5134252, 144.513837, 141.1973268, 
144.5139746, 144.5140505, 141.1766183, 144.5134691, 144.5135429, 
144.5135725, 141.1637675, 141.1637329, 141.163436, 141.4268554, 
141.1048483, 141.1057649, 141.1159003, 141.426875, 141.4268694, 
141.1266887, 141.4969998, 141.1636342, 144.4753832, 144.4757065, 
144.4757223, 144.4758371, 144.4701818, 144.4694723, 144.468609, 
144.4685023, 144.4682242, 144.4618606, 144.4623245, 144.4622704, 
150.7387821, 142.2014623, 142.20054, 142.1664427, 142.1653236, 
142.1555113, 142.1546404, 142.2538098, 142.1443527, 142.2499897, 
142.1348173, 142.1321397, 142.2527264, 142.2448387, 142.2375661, 
142.2379506, 142.2384398, 142.1788876, 142.240999, 142.242082, 
142.2444854, 142.2448551, 142.2474832, 142.2477227, 142.1237311, 
142.2496503, 142.2531736, 142.123925, 142.1245098, 142.1230175, 
142.121016, 142.1206332, 142.1162641, 142.1371831, 142.1416647, 
142.1456774, 142.1462332, 142.1462307, 142.2317248, 142.2320715, 
142.2330302, 142.1546964, 142.2341506, 142.1563183, 142.2349397, 
142.1562719, 142.2354367, 142.2364275, 142.1947453, 142.2359872, 
142.1979139, 142.2371549, 142.1987077, 142.2358116, 142.2009847, 
146.66957, 116.1108423, 144.4910568, 116.2274227, 116.0813997, 
144.0384116, 144.0385225, 144.0379672, 116.1315572, 116.3974934, 
116.3903852, 116.4503167, 143.3177009, 143.30871, 143.3138509, 
143.3172795, 143.3184864, 143.3087774, 143.3165288, 143.3181195, 
143.316631, 116.3962186, 144.3584108, 144.3587695, 144.3596103, 
144.3595237, 144.3589505, 144.3584941, 144.3587878, 144.3588112, 
144.3584025, 144.3585849, 116.17794, 143.3206132, 143.3178381, 
143.3158327, 143.3155574, 143.3140693, 143.315339, 143.3156289, 
143.3167075, 143.3178058, 143.317534, 143.317725, 143.3170416, 
143.3146147, 143.3129991, 143.0474129, 143.0480077, 143.0482198, 
116.1541254, 116.1524082, 116.1298962, 116.1048619, 115.9903555, 
143.3175007, 143.3195338, 143.3184869, 143.3173438, 143.3156489, 
143.3100567, 143.3101193, 143.3133395, 143.3186712), rhdv = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), control.any = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-671L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Question:** For each record where `dat$rhdv == 1` I would like to identify all other records where `dat$control.any == 1` ONLY IF they fall within a 12 month window (forward and backward) of the given `dat$rhdv == 1` record AND they fall within a 1km radius of the same given `dat$rhdv == 1` record. These records should be identified by assigning a value `1` in a new column, `dat$control.any12`.

I have tried a number of things to achieve this, but so far I have not achieved anything meaningful. My most recent attempt is below

```
# First for each dat$control.any record create a start and end date indicating the date window within which a dat$rhdv == 1 record must fall
dat <- dat %>% mutate(start_date = ifelse(control.any == 1, date - years(1), NA),
               end_date = ifelse(control.any == 1, date + years(1), NA)) %>%
  mutate(start_date = as.Date(start_date, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
         end_date = as.Date(end_date, origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
  fill(c(start_date, end_date), .direction = "downup")

# We are not interested in records where dat$control.any == 0 so assign start and end date value of NA
dat$start_date <- ifelse(dat$control.any == 0, dat$start_date == NA, dat$start_date)
dat$end_date <- ifelse(dat$control.any == 0, dat$end_date == NA, dat$end_date)

# Loop over dat and assign a value of 1 to a new column, control.any12, if the date of any dat$rhdv == 1 record falls within the start and end date of any other dat$control.any == 1 record AND the two records are less than a 1000m apart 
for(i in 1:nrow(dat))
{
  control.any12 = ifelse(any(dat$rhdv[i] == 1) & any(as.numeric(dat$date[i])) > as.numeric(dat$start_date) & any(as.numeric(dat$date[i])) < as.numeric(dat$end_date) & distm(c(dat$Longitude, dat$Latitude), c(any(dat$Longitude[i]), any(dat$latitude[i])), fun = distHaversine) < 1001, 1, 0)
  
}
```

To calculate distances between two point I am trying to use the below from the `geosphere` package

```
distm(c(Longitude1, Latitude1), c(Longitude2, Latitude2), fun = distHaversine)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What packages are you using (i.e., for distance calculation)? When you say they need to fall within a 1km radius of the `dat$rhdv == 1` record, which one? I count 76 that match that criterion. Do you know what the expected output should be given this sample data? (I mean _literally_, as in can you demonstrate which rows are assigned which values?)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited post to include my latest attempt to achieve this solution - unfortunately unsuccessfully. I do not have a *literal* expected output.